# Python- import ipdb fails

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

I'm trying to use Python Debugger.

I don't know what's going wrong here,

```
def main():
    print "over ipdb"
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    low, high = 0, 1
    for i in xrange(10):
        print high
        low, high = high, low + high

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

the terminal keep showing this:

```
over ipdb
Before the function runs
I am a stand alone function, don't you dare modify me
After the function runs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydebudder.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "pydebudder.py", line 5, in main
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipdb/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ipdb.__main__ import set_trace, post_mortem, pm, run, runcall, runeval, launch_ipdb_on_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipdb/__main__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.external.decorator import decorator
ImportError: cannot import name decorator
```

I upgraded ipython to 3.0.0

Comment: what ipython version and package version? Where is *Before the function runs
I am a stand alone function, don't you dare modify me
After the function runs* coming from?

Comment: Install [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) `pip install ipdb`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  ipython version 2.3.1, I had the same issue when I run python script on terminal.

Comment: I would try upgrading ipython, `pip install -U ipython`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I upgraded to 3.0.0, able to import in interactive shell, but i had the same issue on running python script with ipdb

Comment: can you add a minimal example of how you are running it?

Comment: Do you have more than one python 2 installed? What does `which -a python` output?

Comment: do you see `_decorator.py` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/IPython/external/decorator`? add the output of `cat __init__.py` in the decorator directory

Comment: also from Ipython, `import IPython;IPython.__file__`

Comment: No @PadraicCunningham but  I am using **virtualenv** but not activated now. 
`/usr/bin/python`

Comment: you are using virtualenv where?

Comment: Also what version of ipdb are you using?

Comment: virtualenv path - `/home/ganesh/Documents/workspace/my_project/`. ipdb version-0.8